# Routing and middleware for multiple databases in Django

Tags: python, django, django-database

I have a problem correctly setting my middleware and routers to support multiple databases, one for each language (I decided to keep them separate).

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215122/url-and-database-routing-based-on-language), but for now I didn't get much use of it.

In my *settings.py* databases and middleware are defined as follows:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'ru': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db_ru.sqlite3',
    },
    'en': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db_en.sqlite3',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['me.middleware.database_routing.DatabaseRouter']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'me.middleware.database_routing.RouterMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

*database_routing.py* used in `'me.middleware.database_routing'` fully corresponds to [this middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215122/url-and-database-routing-based-on-language).

I get an error when starting the server: *RouterMiddleware() takes no arguments*. I believe there's some shortcoming concerning the middleware code. Also I cannot migrate to my databases, I get `ValueError: Cannot assign "<ContentType: ContentType object (1)>": the current database router prevents this relation.`

Maybe, there is some other solution?

Comment: The structure of middleware has changed, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware). Briefly, if you inherit from `MiddlewareMixin` you should be able to avoid that error.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, what about the `ValueError` when migrating? How to set the router properly?

Answer (score 0):

if your database_routing.py contains the below section, it is stopping the relationships to create in Django.

So, try commenting on the commented lines and return only true.
This worked for me!

```
def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Do not allow relations involving the remote database
        """
        # print("in allow relation")
        # if obj1._meta.app_label == Organization or \
        #    obj2._meta.app_label == Organization:
        #    return True
        # return None
        return True
```